# Minimum-printing program doesn't work

Tags: c, function

```
#include <stdio.h>

float *dupabiskupa(float *tab, int roz)
{
    float *a;
    *a=tab[0];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<roz;i++)
    {
        if(tab[i]<*a)
            *a=tab[i];
    }
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    float wsk;
    int rozmiar;
    int i;
    printf("Podaj rozmiar tablicy \n");
    scanf("%d",&rozmiar);
    float tab1[rozmiar];

    for(i=0; i<rozmiar;i++)
    scanf("%f", &tab1[i]);

    wsk=*dupabiskupa(tab1, rozmiar);
    printf("%f", wsk);
    return 0;
}
```

Why isn't this program working? It compiles with no errors, but when I input a a number the program closes.

Comment: Nothing ++ about this C

Comment: You may want to read [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266563/do-non-english-words-increase-the-probability-of-receiving-downvotes/).

Comment: You may need to pause the program before it returns from main.

Comment: *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers."*

Comment: What do you need the address of the function `dupabiskupa` for?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: no need to pause the program if running it on the command line on Linux or some other Posix system ...

Answer (score 1):

First off, note that the code

```
float *a;
*a=tab[0];
```

has **Undefined Behavior**: it's attempting to store a value at an arbitrary memory location, due to use of uninitialized pointer `a`.

Anything, or nothing, can happen.

Including what you expected to happen.

---

Regarding closing of console window, if that's what this is about.

In Visual Studio, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> to run the program. That keeps the console window open at the end. Other IDEs typically have corresponding functionality.

Or you can run the program from the command line.

Comment: Oops, if anyone saw my comment about uninitialized `i` before I edited it out: I misread the code. :(

Answer (score 1):

Compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). Learn how to use a debugger (`gdb`). Read more about C programming and pointers.

Your first function should be

```
float dupabiskupa(float *tab, int roz) {
  float a;
  if (roz <= 0 || !tab)
    return -INFINITY;
  a=tab[0];
  for(int i=1; i<roz; i++) {
    if(tab[i]<a)
        a=tab[i];
  }
  return a;
}
```

It looks like you did not understand what a pointer is, and why arrays are decayed to pointers in C. Spend several hours reading more your C programming book and playing with the debugger.

And please, read the documentation of every function you are using. Notice that [scanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) returns a result (the number of successfully scanned items), and you should test it.

Be scared of [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).